# uiwebview javascript no return

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, return-value

have a weird behaviour. In a `UIWebView` I have a javacript function to detect the postion of an element. this one:

```
function getPosition(element){

    var el = element;
    var pos = [el.offsetLeft, el.offsetTop];
    var parent = el.offsetParent;
    if (parent != el) {
        while (parent) {
            pos[0] += parent.offsetLeft;
            pos[1] += parent.offsetTop;
            parent = parent.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    //alert(pos);
    return pos;
}
```

nothing special… but when I call the function like that:

```
NSString *position = [browserWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getPosition(document.getElementById('exampleElement'));"];
```

I get an empty `NSString` back. When I insert an alert into the function (which is uncomment right now) I get the correct position in the alert!!

Why do I not get the value back and getting just an empty string when the correct return value `pos` seems to be there?

Answer (score 3):

This is rather simple and a complete mystery to me at the same time. I don't know why but **"stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"** likes for the javascript result to already resemble a string. To fix your code just add a join() function to your returning array:

```
return pos.join();
```

This will join the array into a single string and it will pass as an NSString no problem.

I presume the reason alerts work is that it wouldn't break sites that display data in a similar manner.

Comment: No problem, if my answer works, you might want to accept it. That's how stackoverflow works. Read: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)